# How to make a good validation on laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation

I have data, they look like this:

```
 {
   sender_name : "Real fake sender name",
   recipient_name : "Real fake recipient name",
   goods: [
     {
        "no" : 1
        "name":"Pen",
        "unit": "1",
        "qty":"50",
        "price":"50",
        "amount":"2500",
        "vat_percent":"5",
        "vat_sum": "125",
        "total_sum": "2625"
     }
   ]
 }
```

I need to validate "goods" using extend validator. Here is his code:

```
Validator::extend('invoiceGoods' , function($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {

  $rulesForGoods = [
      'no'          => 'integer|required',
      'name'        => 'string|max:64|required',
      'unit'        => 'required|integer',
      'qty'         => 'required|string',
      'price'       => 'required|numeric',
      'amount'      => 'required|numeric',
      'vat_percent' => 'nullable|numeric',
      'vat_sum'     => 'nullable|numeric',
      'total_sum'   => 'required|numeric'
  ];

  foreach ($value as $good) {
      $validator = Validator::make($good , $rulesForGoods);
      if ($validator->fails()) {
          return false;
      }
  }

  return true;

});
```

This is the main code.

```
$validator = Validator::make($data , [
   'goods' => 'invoiceGoods',
   'sender_name' => 'string',
   'recipient_name' => 'string',
]);

if ($validator->fails()) {
  return response()->json([
    'success' => false,
    'message' => 'Validation error.',
    'data'    => $validator->errors()
  ]);
}
```

If the goods validation error occurs, I get this answer:

[image]

But I would like to display errors like this: the wrong unit in the goods with no 1.

I know that the third argument can be passed an array with custom messages, but how to return it from the extended validator if it should return true or false?

Answer (score 1):

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#custom-error-messages

```
$messages = [
'Validation.invoice_goods' => 'Errror message!',];

$validator = Validator::make($input, $rules, $messages);
```